# How to update records in Airtable using Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, automation, integration, airtable

I have a script that writes the data that is collected from a Google Photos album to Airtable. The script is purely generated from ChatGPT, I have no experience of coding and indeed I don't know how to code. How can I modify the script to update the existing records in batches of 10 (assuming all the existing cells will be empty/blank before updating), instead of creating new records to write the data.

What I actually need is the script to write the data collected from Google Photos to empty cells, which means I will insert empty records into the table in which the data must be written. The script that I currently have skips the empty cells and creates a new record to write the data.

The script that I use to write data to Airtable is:

```js
function listAlbumData() {
  var apiKey = "API_KEY/ACCESS_TOKEN"; //paste your api or access token here
  var baseId = "BASE_ID"; //paste your base id here
  var tableName = "tab3"; //paste your table name here


  // Get albums from Google Photos
  var albums = [];
  var nextPageToken = null;
  do {
    var pageData = getAlbums(nextPageToken);
    if (pageData.albums && Array.isArray(pageData.albums)) {
      albums = albums.concat(pageData.albums);
    }
    nextPageToken = pageData.nextPageToken;
  } while (nextPageToken);


  // Prepare records for Airtable
  var records = [];
  albums.forEach(function(album) {
    var record = {
      "fields": {
        "Album Name": album.title,
        "Number of Photos": album.mediaItemsCount
      }
    };
    records.push(record);
  });


  // Write records to Airtable
  updatetable(records, apiKey, baseId, tableName);
}


function getAlbums(pageToken) {
  var options = {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      "Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()
    },
    muteHttpExceptions: true
  };


  var url = "https://photoslibrary.googleapis.com/v1/albums";
  if (pageToken) {
    url += "?pageToken=" + pageToken;
  }


  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  var data = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());


  return data;
}


function updatetable(records, apiKey, baseId, tableName) {
  var url = "https://api.airtable.com/v0/" + baseId + "/" + tableName;
  var headers = {
    "Authorization": "Bearer " + apiKey,
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  };


  // Batch the records into groups of 10
  var batchSize = 10;
  var batchedRecords = [];
  while (records.length > 0) {
    batchedRecords.push(records.splice(0, batchSize));
  }


  // Send requests for each batch
  batchedRecords.forEach(function(batch) {
    var payload = {
      "records": batch
    };


    var options = {
      "method": "POST",
      "headers": headers,
      "payload": JSON.stringify(payload)
    };


    UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Suggestion:

*This answer is intended to serve as a starting point or
reference for your project. It's important to note that the community members do not provide coding services.*

This is the following modification I've made on your script

1. Added a function `getRecordId` that extracts the ID of an existing empty record on Airtable
2. Change the API endpoint used in `updatetable` function from [Create records](https://airtable.com/developers/web/api/create-records) to [Update record](https://airtable.com/developers/web/api/update-record)
3. Insert the collected google albums to existing empty records based on the number of empty records on Airtable

### Script:

```
function listAlbumData() {
  var apiKey = "API KEY"; //paste your api or access token here
  var baseId = "BASE ID"; //paste your base id here
  var tableName = "TABLE NAME"; //paste your table name here


  // Get albums from Google Photos
  var albums = [];
  var nextPageToken = null;
  do {
    var pageData = getAlbums(nextPageToken);
    if (pageData.albums && Array.isArray(pageData.albums)) {
      albums = albums.concat(pageData.albums);
    }
    nextPageToken = pageData.nextPageToken;
  } while (nextPageToken);


  // Prepare records for Airtable
  var records = [];
  albums.forEach(function (album) {
    var record = {
      "fields": {
        "Album Name": album.title,
        "Number of Photos": album.mediaItemsCount
      }
    };
    records.push(record);
  });
  // Write records to Airtable
  updatetable(records, apiKey, baseId, tableName);
}


function getAlbums(pageToken) {
  var options = {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      "Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()
    },
    muteHttpExceptions: true
  };
  var url = "https://photoslibrary.googleapis.com/v1/albums";
  if (pageToken) {
    url += "?pageToken=" + pageToken;
  }
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  var data = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  return data
}

function updatetable(records, apiKey, baseId, tableName) {
  var recordId = getRecordId(apiKey, baseId, tableName)
  for (var i = 0; i < recordId.length; i++) {
    var url = "https://api.airtable.com/v0/" + baseId + "/" + tableName + "/" + recordId[i];
    var headers = {
      "Authorization": "Bearer " + apiKey,
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    };


    var options = {
      "method": "PATCH",
      "headers": headers,
      "payload": JSON.stringify(records[i])
    };
    UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  };

  //Get the recordId of existing records
  function getRecordId(apiKey, baseId, tableName) {
    var url = "https://api.airtable.com/v0/" + baseId + "/" + tableName;
    var headers = {
      "Authorization": "Bearer " + apiKey,
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    };

    var options = {
      "method": "Get",
      "headers": headers
    };
    result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
    response = JSON.parse(result)
    data = response.records
    var recordId = []
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      recordId.push(data[i].id)
    };
    return recordId
  };

}
```

### Output:

[image]

### Reference:

[Airtable API](https://airtable.com/developers/web/api/introduction)

Comment: @Geroge, thank you so much friend for helping me out again. Your solution is perfect and works!!

Comment: You're welcome @Daniel, I am glad my solution was of help!